# Alinhar ícone com texto verticalmente

Tags: css

Como faço para deixar o ícone alinhado com o texto?

```css
.material-icons {
    width: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.tiny { 
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.small { 
    font-size: 2rem; 
    width: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.medium { 
    font-size: 4rem; 
    width: 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.large { 
    font-size: 6rem; 
    width: 6rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.extra-large { 
    font-size: 10rem; 
    width: 10rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<h1><i class="material-icons medium">error</i>Ops...</h1>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: middle;`.

> **Nota:** uma coisa importante, a propriedade `vertical-align` só funciona com elementos cujo o valor `display` seja `inline` ou `inline-block`, quando usar `float` ou `block` o `vertical-align` não terá efeito, pois ele é usado para elementos que tenham comportamento "inline".

O seu CSS deve ficar assim:

```css
.material-icons {
    width: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.material-icons.tiny { 
    font-size: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.small { 
    font-size: 2rem; 
    width: 2rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.medium { 
    font-size: 4rem; 
    width: 4rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.large { 
    font-size: 6rem; 
    width: 6rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.material-icons.extra-large { 
    font-size: 10rem; 
    width: 10rem;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<h1><i class="material-icons medium">error</i>Ops...</h1>
```

Comment: vlw, obrigado. era isso mesmo