# Centralizar texto verticalmente

Tags: css

Eu estou tentando fazer uma DIV pra uma assinatura com uma foto (24x24) ao lado.

Eu quero centralizar este texto verticalmente, de acordo com o tamanho da foto. Eu tentei usar `vertical-align: middle`, mas não me pareceu surtir efeito.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #444;
  color: #FFF;
}

.assinatura {
  vertical-align: middle;  
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<footer style="float: right;">
    <div class="assinatura">
        Este texto eu quero no centro
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3Te.png?s=24&g=1" />
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: É, eu cheguei a ver esta resposta, mas não tinha me ligado que o alinhamento estava na tag errada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se eu entendi bem, mas só faltou você adicionar a classe assinatura na imagem.

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #444;
  color: #FFF;
}

.assinatura {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<footer style="float: right;">
  <div>
    Este texto eu quero no centro
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3Te.png?s=24&g=1" class="assinatura" />
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta colocar `vertical-align: middle;` na tag `img`, então os textos `inline` que estão junto a imagem irão acompanhar a sua "base", com isto também é possível ajustar a base abaixo dos textos ou acima, semelhante a esta [Alinhar ícone com texto verticalmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179646/3635)

Um exemplo:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  font: 14px Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #444;
  color: #FFF;
}

footer > div > img {
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
```

```html
<footer style="float: right;">
    <div>
        Este texto eu quero no centro
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3Te.png?s=24&g=1" />
    </div>
</footer>
```